# ValueError: Unexpected output from check_file_exists when loading file via SCP to NXOS (9.2.2) device

Tags: automation, python-3.7, cisco

I'm trying to load `.txt` file via netmiko and SCP to cisco NXOS 9000 device
But error

> ValueError: Unexpected output from check_file_exists occured.

When I try to load file in traditional way (for example via scp client on Ubuntu) to cisco Nexus device its work fine.

Some manipulations with `file_transfer` options (like removing and changing file_system param's didn't help to resolve issue)

```
from yaml import safe_load
from netmiko import Netmiko, file_transfer
import os
import sys

os.chdir("/root/PycharmProjects/Netprog_Pluralsight/SECTION_02/06")

def main():
    with open("/root/PycharmProjects/Netprog_Pluralsight/SECTION_02/02/hosts.yml", "r") as handle:
        host_root = safe_load(handle) 
        for host in host_root["host_list"]:
            platform = host["platform"] 

            conn = Netmiko(
                host = host["ip"],
                username = "admin",
                password = "admin",
                device_type=platform,
            )
            print("""logged to device {} successfully""".format(host["ip"])) #здесь для появления айпишника куда лезем настраивать добавляем этот принт

            result = file_transfer(
                conn,
                source_file = "FOR_DOWNLOAD.txt",
                dest_file = "FOR_DOWNLOAD.txt",
                file_system = 'bootflash:',
            )
            print(f"Details: {result}\n")
            conn.disconnect()


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by replacing Netmiko ==> ConnectHandler